# How to include absolute path in C++

Tags: c++, cmake, structure

#### Project Sturcture

I am learning how to build a C++/cmake template. The structure looks like:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── geometry
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── line
            ├── CMakeLists.txt
            ├── line.cpp
            └── line.h
```

#### Every `CMakeLists.txt` looks like the following:

`./CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.0)
project(cmake_template VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

`./src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(geometry)
```

`./src/geometry/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(line)
```

`./src/geometry/line/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(line line.cpp)
target_include_directories(line PUBLIC .)
```

#### And the implementation looks like:

`line.h`:

```
#include <string>

class Line{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    Line(std::string);
    virtual void display();
};
```

`line.cpp`:

```
#include "src/geometry/line/line.h"
#include <iostream>

Line::Line(std::string name):name(name){}

void Line::display(){
    std::cout << "A line with name " << this->name << "\n";
}
```

#### Compile and error

The command I run is `cmake -S . -B build && cmake --build build/`, and it shows the error:

```
[1/2] Building CXX object src/geometry/line/CMakeFiles/line.dir/line.cpp.o
FAILED: src/geometry/line/CMakeFiles/line.dir/line.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/clang++  -I../src/geometry/line/. -g -MD -MT src/geometry/line/CMakeFiles/line.dir/line.cpp.o -MF src/geometry/line/CMakeFiles/line.dir/line.cpp.o.d -o src/geometry/line/CMakeFiles/line.dir/line.cpp.o -c ../src/geometry/line/line.cpp
../src/geometry/line/line.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'src/geometry/line/line.h' file not found
#include "src/geometry/line/line.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

The code can compile if I change to `#include "line.h"`

#### My questions are:

- How can I include the absolute path without change the current structure? I.e., I don't want to change `CMakeLists.txt` in the upper level, only `./src/geometry/line/CMakeLists.txt` can be changed.
- How can I use `<>` to include the absolute path? I.e., `#include <src/geometry/line/line.h>`? The reason of using `<>` is from the [Canonical CPP Project Structure](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1204r0.html#src-dir).

Comment: You may try: `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`. And then include just `<line.h>`.

Comment: I don't want to include just `<line.h>`.

Comment: If you want to include `<src/geometry/line/line.h>` instead of `<line.h>` then you need to add include_directories path like that.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer, and the answer is none of the answer mentioned by stackoverflow btw. (So, I don't know why this question is closed...) I forgot to add that I try to follow the best practice (so `include_directories` is not an option here). Anyway, the answer is replacing `target_include_directories(line PUBLIC .)` with `target_include_directories(line PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})` in `./src/geometry/line/CMakeLists.txt`.